# Updating cells in UICollectionView that scrolls - app crashes when deleting off-screen cells

Tags: ios, xcode, scroll, uicollectionview

My app consists of a `UICollectionView` that displays a number of custom subviews for a card matching game. Basically, when three cards match, the cells containing them are deleted from the collection view. My delete function works when all three cells are visible on a scrollable screen, but not when one or two are off-screen. What happens is the cell on-screen would be deleted, but the moment I try to scroll up for the other ones (which are supposed to be deleted as well) the app crashes.

Below is the code for my card update function:

```
- (void) updateCell: (SetCardCell*) cell withCard: (SetsCard *) cardInModel {
    if ([cell isKindOfClass: [SetCardCell class]]){
        if ([cell.setCardView isKindOfClass:[SetCardView class]]) {

            // various actions to match view with model

            SetCardView *cardView = cell.setCardView;
            [cardView setNeedsDisplay];

            // do things to UI if card is faced up or unplayable

            if (!cardInModel.isUnplayable) {
                if (cardInModel.isFaceUp) {
                    cell.setCardView.alpha = 0.3;
                } else {
                    cell.setCardView.alpha = 1;
                }
            } else {
                // remove the cell - this is where the problem is

                NSLog(@"%@", cell.description);  ** returns a cell ** 
                NSLog(@"%@", [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell].description); ** returns (null) when the cell is offscreen, but a normal index path if otherwise **

                [self.game.cards removeObjectsInArray:@[cardInModel]];
                [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell]]];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you very much!

Edit: I forgot that an error message is raised as below:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've seen, you get a nil index path for a cell that isn't currently visible when using `indexPathForCell`. This then causes a crash when you try to create an array out of it to pass to the delete method. The delete method itself isn't crashing, just making an array.

You shouldn't be driving your updates using cells. As soon as possible you need to get a reference to an object in your *model*, and derive index paths and perform deletions from that. The cell is just part of the representation of your model.

Looking at your code, a possible fix is to derive the index path from `cardInModel`'s position in its array (before you remove it?)

Comment: Thank you, I changed my code to :
`NSIndexPath *indexPathToBeRemoved = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.game.cards indexOfObject:cardInModel] inSection:0];
[self.game.cards removeObjectsInArray:@[cardInModel]];  
[self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathToBeRemoved]];`

I no longer get exceptions, but the cells are not deleted completely. As the remaining views are shifted over, the views that should have been deleted stay in the background of the new cells, so that there is overlap between the two views. These old views are not affected by changes at all, unlike the new views

Comment: You have to remove the old subviews from the cells before you reuse them.

Easiest way to do this is something like the following:

[cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];

Comment: @RegularExpression is probably right. Your new issue sounds like a cell reuse problem.

Comment: @RegularExpression I have tried putting the code you suggested before deleting items from the collection view. It got rid of the overlap problem but some random cells now just disappear when I delete cells. They are still clickable and they still have content, they are just not visible. The cells (just cells in the collection view, not even the ones where the deleted cells used to be) would just appear / disappear randomly when I scroll up and down. Do you have any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: @RegularExpression Actually, I've checked more carefully and the overlap problem is still there, even with your code. Is it possible that by deleting the subviews before removing the cell, the next time the cell is reused it will not have the subview anymore?

Comment: @merah I think you need to ask a separate question. This isn't related to your original issue, and you're more likely to get an answer with a new question than by having a chat in the comments to another answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this:

```
[self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell]]];
```

and the indexPath returns nil (as it likely will if the cell is not currently displayed), you would get an exception as deleteItemsAtIndexPaths cannot be passed a nil.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention the exception! Here it is: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'`

Comment: That's not the exception I expected you were getting.  Which line, exactly, are you getting the exception on?  If it is the second NSLog, you know you're getting a nil for either the cell or the description.   really would inspect each variable in those statements w/debugger as the problem has to be in one of them.

Comment: I was getting exceptions on this line:
`[self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell]]];` 

I will try the debugger and tell you how it works out